# QT 5.11.3 - QDomNode : can't print value of dom element

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qdomdocument

I'm trying to create a very function to read a very simple XML file and print its content on the QTCreator console.

I created the following XML file :

```
<SCANNERS>
    <SCANNER>
        <NAME>Test scanner</NAME>
        <SERIAL>10102030</SERIAL>
    </SCANNER>
    <SCANNER>
        <NAME>Test scanner 2</NAME>
        <SERIAL>10102031</SERIAL>
    </SCANNER>
    <SCANNER>
        <NAME>Test scanner 3</NAME>
        <SERIAL>10102032</SERIAL>
    </SCANNER>
    <SCANNER>
        <NAME>Test scanner 4</NAME>
        <SERIAL>10102033</SERIAL>
    </SCANNER>
    <SCANNER>
        <NAME>Test scanner 5</NAME>
        <SERIAL>10102034</SERIAL>
    </SCANNER>
</SCANNERS>
```

Then I created the following function, which is supposed to print each nodes inside each "SCANNER" tags :

```
void printDomDocument(QString xml)
{
    QDomDocument xmlScanners;
    QFile file(xml);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        std::cout << "QScannerEntryList : couldn't open XML file : " << xml.toStdString() << std::endl;

    }
    if (xmlScanners.setContent(&file))
    {
        QDomElement elem = xmlScanners.documentElement();
        QDomNode n = elem.firstChild();
        while (!n.isNull())
        {
            QDomElement e = n.toElement(); // try to convert the node to an element.
            if (!e.isNull())
            {
                QDomNode n2 = e.firstChild();
                std::cout << n2.nodeName().toStdString() << " " << n2.nodeValue().toStdString() << std::endl;
                n2 = n2.nextSibling();
                std::cout << n2.nodeName().toStdString() << " " << n2.nodeValue().toStdString() << std::endl;
            }
            n = n.nextSibling();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "QScannerEntryList : couldn't grab content from XML file : " << xml.toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

My problem is, I can print the tagnames of each node perfectly, but for some reason I can't manage to print the values inside each of these tags. n2.nodeValue() doesn't show on the console.

Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what's wrong.

Actually, the actual node value seems to be one node deeper than the child itself.

The solution is simply to "dig" one layer deeper :

```
QDomNode n2 = e.firstChild();
std::cout << n2.nodeName().toStdString() << " " << n2.firstChild().nodeValue().toStdString() << std::endl;
n2 = n2.nextSibling();
std::cout << n2.nodeName().toStdString() << " " << n2.firstChild().nodeValue().toStdString() << std::endl;
```

Returns the expected result :

```
NAME Test scanner
SERIAL 10102030
NAME Test scanner 2
SERIAL 10102031
NAME Test scanner 3
SERIAL 10102032
NAME Test scanner 4
SERIAL 10102033
NAME Test scanner 5
SERIAL 10102034
```